# How to make Visual Studio 2017 remote debugger remember user permissions?

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

If I go to Tools -> Options -> Permissions in the Visual Studio 2017 remote debugger and delete provided default permissions for an administrator and replace it with my own non-interactive user:

[image]

If I close the remote debugger process and then reopen it, it resets permissions to this:

[image]

Is there any way to make it remember those permissions?